# how to transform text with under score to italic during copy-paste in Lexical editor?

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

I'm using Lexical for rich text
here is my lexical code:

```
            <LexicalComposer initialConfig={{
              namespace: 'lexical-editor',
              editorState:  () => $convertFromMarkdownString(description || '', TRANSFORMERS),
              theme: {
                root: 'public-content',
                link: 'cursor-pointer',
                text: {
                  bold: "textBold",
                  italic: "textItalic",
                  underline: "textUnderline",
                },
              },
              onError: error => {
                console.log(error);
              },
              nodes: [ CodeNode, HeadingNode, LinkNode, ListNode, ListItemNode, QuoteNode]
            }}>
              <OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
              <MarkdownShortcutPlugin transformers={TRANSFORMERS} />
              <RichTextPlugin
                contentEditable={<ContentEditable />}
                placeholder={null}
                ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
              />
                <CookingDescriptionEditorToolbar
                  onToggleEditorMode={onToggleEditorMode}
                  editorMode={editorMode}
                  ...
                  id={id}
              />
            </LexicalComposer>
```

could you please let me know how can I transform a text with underscore to italic when I copy paste some text in rich text editor?

Answer (score 0):

This will also transform the text when the user types it (not only on-paste):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";
import { TextNode } from "lexical";

export default function ItalicTextPlugin() {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!editor) return;
    const removeNodeListener = editor.registerNodeTransform(
      TextNode,
      (node) => {
        if (!node) return;
        const textContent = node.getTextContent();

        if (textContent.includes("_") && textContent.length > 1) {
          node.toggleFormat("italic");
          node.setTextContent(textContent.replace("_", ""));
        }
      }
    );
    return () => removeNodeListener();
  }, [editor]);
}
```

Please see this sandbox that I prepared: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-https-ynsf5f?file=/src/plugins/ItalicTextPlugin.js:0-717

***(Edited)***

- As a solution to do this on-paste only, you may register a `window.addEventListener('paste')`,
- and set the global state variable (e.g. using the React Context API)
- `let isOnPaste` to *`true`*,
- and then the Lexical listener will catch up,
- and you can write a handler with an **IF** condition like the following one:

```js
if (contextObject.isOnPaste) {
// other logic and checks, as shown above
contextObject.setIsOnPaste(false);
node.toggleFormat("italic");
node.setTextContent(textContent.replace("_", ""));
// etc...
}
```